# How do I use EditorFor of single model out of collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm relatively new to MVC, but here is what I have:
I have a view which has a model of type `IEnumerable<SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Comment>`

As the name suggests, its for a collection of comments. I also want the user to be able to add a comment to the page. In previous views I used `@Html.EditorForModel()`. This doesn't work because the model is a collection.

So next I tried using `EditorFor()`, So I tried this `@Html.EditorFor(M => M.FirstOrDefault())` , but it isn't working for some reason.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm attempting or am I going to have to code an html widget for each attribute in my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.EditorFor(M => M.FirstOrDefault().FieldName)
```